# Confining text highlighting to <pre> block

Tags: html, css

This must be a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the right keywords to search for. How do I confine text-highlighting (via the cursor) to a particular html element? For instance, I have a `<pre></pre>` block marked up using [prettyprint](https://web.archive.org/web/20081007023058/http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/). Specifically, my highlights spill out the element like so:

[image: yoyoyo]

where the highlight selection should stick to the element of interest (element where the selection began). This isn't a problem in firefox, but is in safari and chrome. Strangely the stackoverflow preview seems to have this functionality despite working in chrome at the present so it must be possible. I couldn't find the right fix by digging through their CSS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just relatively position the element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hJJ9x/) - try highlighting the text after removing `position:relative`.

```
pre {
    position:relative; /* Add this.. */
    background:rgb(216, 216, 216);
    word-break:break-word;
    margin:10px 50px;
}
```